# Missing dependencies gd and libgd.so.2 installing nginx on Centos 6

Tags: centos, nginx

Missing the above dependencies when trying to install Nginx from EPEL on Centos 6.

I've copied the outbpt below:

```
# yum install nginx
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, replace, security
Setting up Install Process
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                                  |  25 kB     00:00     
 * epel: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * extras: ftp.heanet.ie
 * updates: ftp.heanet.ie
epel                                                                                                           | 4.7 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                                | 6.0 MB     00:01     
epel-httpd24                                                                                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                         | 3.4 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                                                                              |  28 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                             | 3.2 MB     00:00     
22 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nginx-all-modules = 1.10.2-1.el6 for package: nginx-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nginx-filesystem = 1.10.2-1.el6 for package: nginx-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nginx-filesystem for package: nginx-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx-all-modules.noarch 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-http-geoip = 1.10.2-1.el6 for package: nginx-all-modules-1.10.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-http-image-filter = 1.10.2-1.el6 for package: nginx-all-modules-1.10.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-http-perl = 1.10.2-1.el6 for package: nginx-all-modules-1.10.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter = 1.10.2-1.el6 for package: nginx-all-modules-1.10.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-mail = 1.10.2-1.el6 for package: nginx-all-modules-1.10.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: nginx-mod-stream = 1.10.2-1.el6 for package: nginx-all-modules-1.10.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package nginx-filesystem.noarch 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx-mod-http-geoip.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: GeoIP for package: nginx-mod-http-geoip-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libGeoIP.so.1()(64bit) for package: nginx-mod-http-geoip-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package nginx-mod-http-image-filter.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd for package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package nginx-mod-http-perl.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package nginx-mod-mail.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package nginx-mod-stream.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GeoIP.x86_64 0:1.6.5-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: GeoIP-data for package: GeoIP-1.6.5-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: geoipupdate for package: GeoIP-1.6.5-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package nginx-mod-http-image-filter.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd for package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GeoIP-GeoLite-data.noarch 0:2018.04-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: GeoIP-GeoLite-data-extra = 2018.04-1.el6 for package: GeoIP-GeoLite-data-2018.04-1.el6.noarch
---> Package geoipupdate.x86_64 0:3.1.1-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package nginx-mod-http-image-filter.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd for package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GeoIP-GeoLite-data-extra.noarch 0:2018.04-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package nginx-mod-http-image-filter.x86_64 0:1.10.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd for package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: gd
Error: Package: nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.10.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgd.so.2()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: I can find `gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm` under the [CentOS 6 base repo](http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/Packages/). Have you disabled this repo? It doesn't show up in your `yum` output.

Comment: Ah, that was it. Editing `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` to reenable the repo got it installed. I must have disabled it at some point. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer, since it seems to have resolved the OP's problem.

The [gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm](http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/Packages/gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm) package corresponding to the OP's system (CentOS 6, x86-64) is available in the 'base' repository for CentOS 6.

The `yum` output shown in the question shows the repository data being downloaded and cached for all enabled repositoires. The 'base' repository is absent from this list. Therefore, the 'base' repository is most likely be disabled on the OP's system.

The 'base' repo can be re-enabled by editing the `CentOS-Base.repo` file under the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory, and setting the parameter `enabled = 1`.

This can also be done in a more straightforward manner by using the `yum-config-manager` tool. Simply run the command `yum-config-manager --enable base` to enable the repo.